# Invalid argument error when I want to instantiate i2c device in linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, i2c

I have an RTC chip on my board that I want to add it to linux as i2c device. I have an script that runs at startup of my embedded linux and in it I have this line :

```
echo ds1337 0x68 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-3/new_device
```

sometimes it works, but sometimes it gives an error :

```
root@t1042d4rdb:~# echo ds1337 0x68 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-3/new_device
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

how I can fix this unstablity ?

Comment: I would use `i2ctransfer` for this, not plain echo.

Comment: as I read about this command, it uses for writing in i2c devices like i2cset , but I want to add my device and introduce device to OS to be able to read and write to it

Comment: Then you need to write a low-level driver. I have never done this before, as I have written only drivers on top of an existing I2C infrastructure. What is easier in the end depends on what environment (particularly programming language) you want to use to talk to your device.

Comment: Why don't you add the RTC in your device tree?

Comment: thank you, It can be a solution that I must test it. but my question is about "invalid argument" in that command! because this command is correct!

Comment: So, what is the problem to add it to your Device Tree Source file, compile and use?

Answer (score 0):

After sending the command after boot for the first time you will see that it throws this error when you try to send it again.